# Single service with multiple AIDL interfaces in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

How can I serve multiple AIDL interfaces from a single Service? The scenario is the following:

```
                    |---Client_1
          |--AIDL1--|     ...
          |         |---Client_6
MyService |
          |         |---Client_4
          |--AIDL2--|     ...
                    |---Client_9
```

- Single service with multiple AIDL;
- Each client may access any number of AIDL interfaces;
- For better understanding consider the diagram above, where some clients (e.g. Client_1, Client_8) only use one interface, while other clients (e.g. Client_4, Client_5, Client_6) access both AIDL1 and AIDL2.

My idea was to use the intent from the method `public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)` to somehow find out *the type of client application calling* and *the AIDL* in which this client is interested in. Is this possible?

Comment: sure,  just return different IBinders in your service's onBind method

Comment: if you don't know how to implement it on the service side see  Api Demos,  file RemoteService .java

Answer (score 3):

I also have the same question and write the prototype for testing.
Actually it should works by examine the intent and return different binder according to the intent extras.

But after testing, I found the onBind only call once for the first client.
After that, system will return the cached binder to later clients who want to bind the service.

Android [official document](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) describe

> Multiple clients can connect to the service at once. However, the system calls your service's onBind() method to retrieve the IBinder only when the first client binds. The system then delivers the same IBinder to any additional clients that bind, without calling onBind() again.

I still try to find ways but it seems not possible to do that.

Comment: I'm using two different client applications and was able to return different AIDLs. In the `onBind` I'm checking the app full name using `intent.getAction()` and return different interfaces according to that. It appears to work. Also, in each client application I bind to the service in `onResume` and unbind on `onPause`, not sure if that makes a difference in your case.